# How to achieve following output : a3b1z2 from input : aaazzb | python |

Tags: python

I am trying to define logic. But some where I am messing up.

**My code :**

```
strname='aaazzb'
get_first_char=strname[0]
result = ''
output=''
cnt = 0
for ch in strname:
  if ch ==  get_first_char:
    result = ch
    cnt = cnt + 1
    temp=result
  else:
    output = output + temp + str(cnt)
    get_first_char = strname[cnt]
    cnt = 1 
print(output)
```

**Expected output :**

```
a3b1z2
```

Comment: You just need to handle the final sequence.  Take the first two lines of your `else:`, and add them after the end of the loop.

Comment: @TimRoberts  : Can you share your sample code. I tried that as well seems no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Counter()` to count elements in the sorted string. And finally add it to a word.

```
from collections import Counter

strname = 'aaazzb'

# count appearances after sorting the string
apperance_counter = Counter(sorted(strname))

# join them to a string
results = ''.join(f'{key}{value}' for key, value in apperance_counter.items())

print(results)
#a3b1z2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the simple solution using **sorted()** and **concatenation**

```
strname='aaazzb'
y = sorted(strname)
temp_storage_for_checks = []
res = ''
for i in y:
    if i not in temp_storage_for_checks:
        temp_storage_for_checks.append(i)
        x = y.count(i)
        res = res + i + str(x)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, using `re.sub` with a callback function:

```py
inp = "aaazzb"
output = re.sub(r'((.)\2*)', lambda m: m.group(2) + (str(len(m.group(1))) if len(m.group(1)) > 1 else ''), inp)
print(output)  # a3z2b
```

The idea is to match every consecutive sequence of 1 or more letter(s), then replace with the letter followed by the count.

Comment: can you explain in detail  step by step. you have written in one line become even more difficult to understand

Comment: Should it also be sorted a-z?

Comment: That was not the initial requirement.  The OP changed after I gave this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I took a reference from author : @Prakash Dahal and was able to define another approach using `for loop`

Thank you : @Prakash Dahal

**My code :**

```
from collections import Counter

#Input
strname='aaazbcb'

# result : Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'z': 1})
result = Counter(sorted(strname))

#Initial counter varaibale set to zero
count = 0

# Output port set to none and later used for concatenation
output=''

for i in result:
  output = output + ( i +  str(result[i]))
  count = count + 1
print(output)
```

**Output :**

```
a3b2c1z1
```